# Why does wmic lie about its output for "BytesReceivedPersec" and "BytesSentPersec"?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, wmic

Take this command:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfRawData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface get BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec
```

It currently outputs, for me, for a computer running over 11 hours:

```
BytesReceivedPersec  BytesSentPersec
11588538117          926338643
```

This means, in human terms:

```
11.59 GB
926.34 MB
```

This is in line with the **total** traffic which I believe that I've received and sent today. But that makes no sense, since the columns say "PerSec".

To get the actual number, I should have to take those number of bytes and multiply them by "the number of seconds my computer has been running", which is currently 39882 (about 11 hours). But if I do that, I get an **insanely** large figure:

```
11588538117 * 39882 = 462.17 TB
926338643 * 39882 = 36.94 TB
```

If I have been pulling down 462 terabytes and sending 36 terabytes of data today, something is horribly, horribly wrong. The first figures, which are "per second", seem to actually correspond to the "total since the computer was turned on", which is what I'm after.

So why are they called "PerSec"? Why is the command lying? Or do I have an unexpectedly fast Internet connection and my computer is secretly being used as a central Internet hub routing most of the Internet's traffic?

Answer (score 3):

Class `Win32_PerfRawData` has "Raw" data, it needs to be processed before it shows the actual stats. You must instead use the class `Win32_PerfFormattedData`
which has "Formatted" data. That'll mean:

```
wmic path Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface get BytesReceivedPersec,BytesSentPersec
```

For example:
[image]
Which cannot be right, even my bandwidth wouldnt't allow that. However:
[image]

[[Reference 1 on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24740683/13611174)] [[Reference 2](https://ethernetandcoffee.gvolk.com/posts/windows-formatted-versus-raw-perf-counters/)] [[Reference 3](https://thwack.solarwinds.com/product-forums/server-application-monitor-sam/f/forum/32961/win32_perfrawdata-vs-win32_perfformatteddata-in-apm/127229)]
Although I didn't find any *official* documentation...But I myself know this to be true. 
One more thing — Computers never 'lie', they just do whatever and however they're told to do. If you say 'lie', its almost like asking a question and expecting answer for another question.